# Creating avro::DataFileReader with avro::memoryInputStream

Tags: c++, avro, unique-ptr

I am trying to read an avro file using the avrocpp library, and I am required to use an external read function which reads the file into a buffer (the file itself is unavailable to me). When I have the file locally, I create a DataFileReader using the constructor with the file name parameter, like this:

```
avro::DataFileReader<avro::GenericDatum> reader("MyAvroFile.avro");
```

and it works great, but when i only have the buffer, I have to pass an InputStreamPtr to the constructor, and the only way to create that with the data from my buffer is via the avro::memoryInputStream function, like this:

```
avro::DataFileReader<avro::GenericDatum> reader(avro::memoryInputStream(buffer, fileSize));
```

This is where I get the following error

```
Exception thrown at 0x0FD5F6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in AvroTestReader.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

And when I try debugging, i notice it happens in the DataFileReader constructor, here:

```
DataFileReader(std::unique_ptr<InputStream> inputStream) :
    base_(new DataFileReaderBase(std::move(inputStream))) {
    base_->init();
}
```

and that the inputStream pointer I passed to it (which should have been created in the avro::memoryInputStream(buffer,filesize) call) is empty. The buffer is properly created so there is no problem there, and I don't have the slightest idea what the problem could be. Also, because InputStreamPtr is a unique_ptr by definition, I don't understand how to correctly pass it to a constructor which requires a parameter passed by value rather than by reference (when i tried initializing it independently, and then passing it to the DataFileReader constructor, I got an error because unique_ptr cannot be copied). Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `filesize` match the size of `buffer`? Where does `buffer` come from? The documentation mentions that "[memoryInputStream] does not copy the data, the byte array should remain valid until the InputStream is used. "

Comment: Yes, everything regarding the buffer is correct, and during debugging, I can see that the InputStreamPtr is correctly created and initialized with the data from the buffer, so it's strictly a matter of how to properly create the DataFileReader using an InputStream.

Comment: I just noticed you are linking against ucrtbased.dll, are you also linking against a debug version of libavro?

Comment: As for your second question, I believe you have to pass an rvalue reference using `DataFileReader(std::move(myptr))`, which resolves to the `unique_ptr(unique_ptr&&)` move constructor.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. In 

`DataFileReaderBase::DataFileReaderBase(std::unique_ptr<InputStream> inputStream) :
    filename_(NULL), stream_(std::move(inputStream)),
    decoder_(binaryDecoder()), objectCount_(0), eof_(false)
{
    readHeader();
}`

, which is the DataFileReaderBase constructor, called inside the DataFileReader constuctor, there is an initialization of a string with NULL:

`filename_(NULL)`

 and as it turns out, that is illegal and will cause an exception. So I'm guessing the avro library for cpp is just badly written.